# NS struct equivalent?

Tags: objective-c

I want to transport an array / NSArray of a particular container across a few methods from different classes. In C++, I'd use something like a Vector of structs.

The container could be represented in a struct like this:

```
struct test
{
    NSString * a;
    NSString * b;
    NSNumber * c;
}
```

The container basically needs to hold some strings and numbers.

Is there an alternative to using structs in Objective C? Is there some other "container" that I could use to send data?

Comment: You can subclass NSObject and give the subclass 3 properties (a,b,c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend creating a simple object, something like this (compiled in my browser):

```
@interface Container : NSObject {
    NSString* a;
    NSString* b;
    NSString* c;
}

@property (retain) NSString* a;
@property (retain) NSString* b;
@property (retain) NSString* c;

@end


@implementation Container

@synthesize a, b, c;

- (void) dealloc {
    [a release];
    [b release];
    [c release];
    [super release];
}
@end
```

Comment: This is better than structs - Apple expressly recommends against mixing structs and objects, in fact, and this code is forward-compatible with ARC, which could save you major headaches.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is exactly the purpose of objects (@interface), in fact objective-c classes are just structs at the end of the day, the apple developer documentation encourages you to create classes instead of using structs.

Answer (score 0):

`NS(Mutable)Dictionary` can act as a generic container for such things, but it's usually better to create a class instead of using dictionaries that always have the same keys.